# How to perform cross server insert in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have 3 tables in 2 servers.

1. Table A in server A
2. Table B in Server B
3. Table C in Server B

Server A and Server B are linked.

Table A:

```
Fruit   Quantity   Total Price
Apple     2            4 
Banana    4           12
Orange    6           24
```

Table B:

```
Fruit    Unit Price 
Apple        2
Banana       3
Orange       4
```

Table C:

```
Fruit   Quantity    Unit Price   Total Price
Apple     2             2             4 
Banana    4             3            12
Orange    6             4            24
```

I'm required to fetch data from Table A to Table C. 
I also need to refer to Table B to get the Unit Price which is needed for Table C.
What I did is:

```
insert into [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table C]
select 
Fruit, Quantity, '', Total Price 
from table A
```

But I am still unable to get the Unit Price of fruit.
May I know what kind of query can I use to get the Unit Price and put into the select query above?

Comment: your question is on `cross server insert` or `getting Unit Price` ?

Comment: @Squirrel my question is on how to get the Unit Price and then apply in the insert query above

Comment: Maybe this `insert into [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table C] select a.Fruit, a.Quantity, b.[unit price], a.[Total Price] from table A join [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table B] B on A.fruit = B.fruit`? Also, do you really need table b since table a's total/qty would give you the same result as the data in b?

Comment: where are you executing the query ? Server A or B ?

Comment: server A @Squirrel

Comment: @zedfoxus But the decimal places for total and unit price are different, output is not very 100% accurate if I divide like that. Btw, your query works. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Karl got it. That makes sense. I have added that as an answer. That way, you can wait for more answers and then put closure to your question by marking one of the answers as accepted. I encourage you to mark answers to your other questions as accepted if they helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    with temp as 
    (
    select 
    A.Fruit, A.Quantity, B.[Unit Price], A.[Total Price] 
    from [Server A].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table A]
    inner join [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table B] on A.Fruit=B.Fruit
    )

    insert into [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table C]
    select A.Fruit, A.Quantity, B.[UnitPrice], A.[Total Price] from temp

---Or---

    insert into [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table C]
    select   A.Fruit, A.Quantity, B.[Unit Price], A.[Total Price] 
    from [Server A].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table A]
    inner join [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table B] on A.Fruit=B.Fruit
```

Of course, You can do it using `Linked Server` [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

I suppose you've already set it up

Comment: isn't `Table A` in `Server A` ?

Comment: Yes, You're right? but it's not very important because it's the only example, anyway, thank you for your attention

Answer (score 2):

To be complete with the answer, you could do this:

```
insert into [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table C]
select a.Fruit, a.Quantity, b.[unit price], a.[Total Price]
from table A
join [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table B] B on A.fruit = B.fruit
```

**Explanation**

You join your `table a` with `table b` so you can get unit price from `b` and rest of the data from `a`. That can be used to insert data into `c`

Answer (score 1):

This query may work for you.

```
insert into [Server B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Table C]
select 
A.[Fruit], A.[Quantity], B.[Unit Price], A.[Total Price]
from A join B
ON A.[Fruit] = B.[Fruit]
```